# Extract parts of a string and paste it to the other "groups"

Tags: r, string

Here I have a simple string;

```
input_string <- "P24928 [1909-1922]; [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; [1923-1936]"
```

I want it to paste the first part, i.e. `P#####`, before the second set of brackets so that the string will be:

```
"P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1922-1923]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1922-1923]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

input_string <- "P24928 [1909-1922]; [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; [1923-1936]"

parts <- input_string |> 
  str_split_1("\\s") |> 
  str_remove(";$")

parts |> 
  matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  mutate(str_c(V1, " ", V2, "; ", V1, " ", V3, "; ")) |> 
  pull(last_col()) |> 
  str_flatten() |> 
  str_remove(";\\s+$")
#> [1] "P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1923-1936]"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gregexpr` to find the `P*\s`-`regmatches`. We want them as substitutes for the nothingness between a semicolon and a space followed by opening bracket. We can do this efficiently with the `` `regmatches<-`() `` function (also shower *@thelatemail* with credits!).

```
> f <- \(x) {
+   sbs <- regmatches(x, gregexpr(r"{P\d+\s(?=\[)}", x, perl=TRUE))
+   mtc <- gregexpr(r"{(?<=;\s)(?=\[)}", x, perl=TRUE)
+   regmatches(x, mtc) <- sbs
+   x
+ }
> f(x)
[1] "P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1923-1936]"
```

Note, that this is already **vectorized**, i.e. you can do the following,

```
> f(c(x, x, x))
[1] "P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1923-1936]"
[2] "P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1923-1936]"
[3] "P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1923-1936]"
```

BTW, it might be more efficient to handle such tasks outside of R. If we were using **awk**, and assuming we have a text file *foo.txt* with lines formatted as `x`, we could approach it like this:

```
$ awk -v OFS=' ' '{print $1, $2, $1 FS $3, $4, $5, $4 FS $6}' foo.txt
P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1923-1936]
P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1923-1936]
P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1923-1936]
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- "P24928 [1909-1922]; [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; [1923-1936]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more:

```
library(tidyverse)

input_string %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep = " ") %>% 
  group_by(group =as.integer(gl(n(),3,n()))) %>% 
  mutate(x = paste(first(value), value)) %>% 
  filter(grepl("\\[", x)) %>% 
  pull() %>% 
  paste(., collapse = " ")
```

```
[1] "P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1923-1936]"
```

Comment: pasting first and then using `filter` was the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more concise solution using some regex:

```
library(tidyverse)
as.data.frame(input_string) %>%
  separate_rows(input_string, sep = "(?<=;)\\s(?=[A-Z])") %>%
  mutate(input_string = str_replace_all(input_string, "(\\w+)(.*?;)(.*$)", "\\1\\2 \\1\\3")) %>%
  summarise(input_string = str_c(input_string, collapse = " "))
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  input_string                                                                  
  <chr>                                                                         
1 P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1923-1936]
```

We first separate the string into its groups using positive look-behind (`(?<=;)`) and look-ahead terms (`(?=[A-Z])`, which implement an instruction to separate at that whitespace where there is a semicolon on the left and a capital letter on the right. Then we define the resulting strings as three capturing groups, which we refer back to using backreferences `\\1`, `\\2`, and `\\3` to paste the first substring after the second substring. Finally we collapse the separated parts back into a single string.

**EDIT**:

If your strings always have six substrings and two 'groups' as in the example, then a simple one-liner suffices:

```
str_replace_all(input_string, "(\\w+)(.*?;)(.*?;) (\\w+)(.*?;)(.*?$)", "\\1\\2 \\1\\3 \\4\\5 \\4\\6")
[1] "P24928 [1909-1922]; P24928 [1923-1936]; P08775 [1909-1922]; P08775 [1923-1936]"
```

But of course this solution an be adapted to more elements per group and more groups ...